# What is the best way to subscribe to a JSON path and listen to the updates that happen at a particular path in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object, jsonpath

I have a simple state management library with a simple store object. Now I want to listen to changes only when a specific part of store changes.

For example-
I want to subscribe to JSON path $subjects.maths.passingmMarks, it should execute a callback.

Now if, initial Store is as below:-

```
const store = {
subjects: {science: {passingMarks: 50}, maths: {passingMarks: 50}}
}

const callback = (state) => {
  console.log('callback :: '+state);
}
```

1. Below code should not execute callback

```
store.setState({subjects: {science: {passingMarks: 60}}});
```

2. Below code should execute callback

```
store.setState({subjects: {maths: {passingMarks: 72}}});
```

```
const isObject = (val) =>
  val != null && typeof val === "object" && Array.isArray(val) === false;

const isEqual = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);


publish(currentState, nextState) {
    if (!isObject(currentState))
      throw new Error("currentState should be and object");
    if (!isObject(nextState)) throw new Error("nextState should be and object");
    for (var key in this.callbackList) {
      const currentValue = JSONPath({ path: key, json: currentState });
      const nextValue = JSONPath({ path: key, json: nextState });
      if (!isEqual(currentValue, nextValue)) {
        const callbacks = this.callbackList[key];
        callbacks.forEach((cl) => {
          cl(nextState);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

The above solution works fine but it has to iterate through the complete callback list, evaluate the currentState and nextState and compare them in order to call a callback for a particular path changes. If there are 1000 subscriber events. Even a single change in store will have to iterate through 1000 callbacks in order to execute the desired callback that has subscribed to the current change. Any suggestions on how we can reduce the number of iterations or any other efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript **Proxy** to track the object and write your handler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

```js
const trackeStore = (store) => {
  const list = {};

  // Deep proxy creater
  function createOnChangeProxy(obj, parent = "", property = "") {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
      get(target, property) {
        const item = target[property]

        if (item && typeof item !== 'function' && !item.parent) {
          parent = parent ? parent + "." + property : property

          Object.setPrototypeOf(item, {
            parent
          });
        }

        if (item && (typeof item === 'object')) return createOnChangeProxy(item, parent, property)

        return item
      },

      set(target, property, newValue) {
        let key = target['parent'] + "." + property
        if (typeof list[key] === "function") {
          list[key]({
            previousValue: target[property],
            newValue,
            property,
            path: key
          });
        }

        target[property] = newValue
        return true;
      },
    })

  }


  // Event listener 
  const storePrototype = {

    addCallback(path, callback) {
      list[path] = callback;
    },

    removeCallback(key) {
      delete list[key];
    },
  };

  Object.setPrototypeOf(store, storePrototype);
  return createOnChangeProxy(store);
};

// Create tracked object
const store = trackeStore({
  subjects: {
    username:"jsfit",
    science: {
      passingMarks: 50
    },
    maths: {
      passingMarks: 50,
     
    }
  },
});

// Register listner
store.addCallback("subjects.maths.passingMarks", (data) => {
  console.log("Listener Value: ", data)
});

store.subjects.maths.passingMarks = 90;
```